# Diff bw columns based on logtime

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum, calculated-columns

My table is:

```
Logtime              Energy
-------------------  --------
2013-02-22 15:30:00  36883.79
2013-02-21 17:30:00  36767.68
2013-02-20 17:30:00  35447.97
2013-02-19 17:30:00  34170.04
2013-02-18 15:30:00  32663.54
2013-02-15 17:30:00  31649.39
2013-02-13 17:30:00  29091.99
2013-02-12 17:30:00  27807.49
```

I need to get the difference between two logtime values.

For example:

Energy difference between `2013-02-18 15:30:00` and `2013-02-22 15:30:00` is `4220.25`.

I tried like this:

```
declare @energy varchar(30)
declare @min int
declare @max int
declare @result varchar(30)
select Logtime,Energy from PLENE_EnergySum order by Logtime desc
set @min=cast((select min(Energy) as [Energy] from PLENE_EnergySum where Logtime between
 '2013-02-22 15:30:00' and  '2013-02-18 15:30:00')as int)
set @max=cast((select max(Energy) as [Energy] from PLENE_EnergySum where Logtime between
'2013-02-22 15:30:00' and  '2013-02-18 15:30:00')as int)
set @result=@max-@min
insert into weekreport values('Fourth',@result)
```

I get null value in my weekreport table

```
week    energy
------  ------
Fourth  NULL
```

Comment: If you got the answer, then please consider posting it as an answer and then accepting it.  Then future visitors to the site will know that this problem was solved and how it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set @first=Cast(Year(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(Month(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+'01'

set @st=Cast(Year(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(Month(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+'08'

set @st1=Cast(Year(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(Month(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+'15'

set @st2=Cast(Year(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(Month(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+'22'

set @st3=Cast(Year(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+Cast(Month(getdate())as varchar(10))+'-'+'32'

set @min=(select min(Energy) as [Energy] from PLENE_EnergySum where Logtime>@first and Logtime<@st)

set @max=(select max(Energy) as [Energy] from PLENE_EnergySum where Logtime>@first and Logtime<@st)

set @result=@max-@min

insert into weekreport(week,Energy) values('First',@result)

Answer for the above table:

First   961.1